# Windows 10 can no longer find Ubuntu Server

Tags: networking, ubuntu, windows-10, ssh, putty

I have a Windows 10 laptop and Ubuntu Server 16.04 setup on my home network. Previously, I've been using Putty to connect via SSH from Windows to Ubuntu without a problem. Today, however, my Windows machine can no longer find the Ubuntu. Both machines are on my home network and are both automatically assigned IPs. I cannot ping the Ubuntu Server from Windows.

I can, however, still connect via SSH to the Ubuntu machine from an app on my phone, and I can still connect remotely through VPN to the Ubuntu machine, so I'm thinking this is a problem with the Windows machine. I was last able to do this two days ago, and the only change that would have occurred on the Windows system is the installation of definition updates for Windows Defender.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Check Windows Firewall.

Comment: Even with Windows Firewall turned off, I'm unable to connect to the server. I should also note that I am able to ping my router from Windows with and without the firewall enabled. I can also ping the router from the Ubuntu machine. I can still connect to the server remotely from my phone.

Comment: Also, the Windows laptop is connected via WiFi, and the Ubuntu machine is connected to the router via Ethernet.

Comment: Test by disabling 'iptables' on the Linux machine.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide IP addresses of both hosts, and perhaps their routing tables as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple all along. I just reset my router, and everything appears to be working!